# Best practices to handle breakpoints with Vue and Tailwind together?

Tags: vue.js, responsive-design, tailwind-css

I'm trying to build a reponsive design using VueJS and Tailwind.
Until now, for this purpose, I was using Tailwind only, this way:

```html
<!-- Mobile view -->
<div class="md:hidden"> some mobile content </div>

<!-- Tablet/Desktop view -->
<div class="hidden md:block"> some tablet/desktop content </div>
```

This kind of worked, but I quickly realized both contents from both views are displayed in the same time in the DOM, and this raises errors in some specific cases (for example, a `Dialog` component from Tailwind HeadlessUI requires to NOT have a sibling `Dialog` component to works properly.)

But from what I understood, tailwind by itself can not remove elements from the DOM, only Vue can do it, using sort of `v-if` logic.

After googling I saw some librairies like [Vue Breakpoints](https://github.com/apertureless/vue-breakpoints) or [Vue MQ](https://github.com/AlexandreBonaventure/vue-mq) that are supposed to fill those needs but:

- How to they integrate with Tailwind? I don't want to define my breakpoints twice (not DRY).
- Do I really need one of them after all? (I'm not fan of adding packages if I don't need to)

It seems there are many ways to do what I want to, but some of them could get easily dirty. Please share any knowledge about how do it well.

Comment: I have the same concerns. Which approach/lib did you use in the end?

Comment: @AndreFigueiredo I used no additional tool and decided to use responsiveness at its max potential. Which means I add the HTML only once to the DOM, and use responsive breakpoints to make it look like I want. It's not as hard as I thought initially, and solve the issues I mentionned.